# How customer can upload the image in product magento?

Tags: magento, upload, product

I want to upload the image at the front end of the product view page
but i don't know how to do these so if anybody know the answer then replay me.

I see the some extension but its not work properly

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Magento has out of the box custom options. You can add new custom options with type file.
Check it, possible it helps in your case.

Comment: ya but afrer that i also display that image in front end